# In Autodesk Forge 2D .dwg drawings is space/region selection possible?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge

Autodesk Forge :In case of 2D .dwg drawings is space/region selection possible? in .rvt files the region/space selection is possible can we have a similar selection in .dwg files also?
from 1st pic if we select a particular room the selection should look as in the second pic is that possible?

Comment: I don't see pic, if I understand correctly, you want to select space\region from LMV (Viewer)? is something like this https://i.vgy.me/qXkAW0.png

Comment: yes it is, needs a selection like that, the space bounded by the lines should get selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. In a 2D drawing, that region is like empty space, you can't select it.

Comment: okay. thank you for your reply. Is there any other method so that we could shade that region with a particular colour or pattern.

Comment: You can start here: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/scene-builder/ then go to next step